# Accurate method or instrument to measure density of shaving cream foam or whipped cream foam?

Tags: density, home-experiment, experimental-technique, applied-physics, instrument

I am currently filling a "standard" stainless steel cup of known volume with foam and then I weigh it. Then I calculate density. 
This method is pretty messy and I have to be careful about how I fill the stainless steel cup so that larger air pockets aren't trapped on accident. I need to figure out a less messy and more reliable method that would allow me to read or calculate specific gravity of the foam more frequently.

I tried fabricating a tube that could be filled with foam from one end and then just scrape the excess foam on both ends, but it turned out to be messier than the original method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to measure the foam density not only frequently but over a long period of time, I'd consider developing an optical method. The attenuation of a low power laser beam passing through a fixed thickness of foam will correlate with the foam density (more bubble walls per cm to scatter the light for a denser foam).

You could probably measure the beam attenuation very easily. Harder would be the calibration of your instrument. This would involve using it for samples of known density, found, presumably, by a direct method such as the one you describe. So this optical method would have no advantage in the short term.

[I toyed with the idea of dropping spheres of the foam through still air and measuring their terminal velocities (proportional to $(\rho_\text{foam}-\rho_\text{air}))$, but coaxing the foam to form spheres would probably be too difficult.]

Comment: +1, an optical method would be very good for repeatability. I would recommend passing the foam through a tube with windows for the light to keep the diameter of the foam fixed.